# How to show all objectclasses description of ldap directory using jndi

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I want to show all objectclasses present in schema of LDAP Directory to help user to input available objectclasses for adding new entry.

```
DirContext schema = ctx.getSchema("");
Attributes answer = schema.getAttributes("ClassDefinition/person");
```

but that shows information about person only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to query the subschema subentry i.e cn=schema
(the below code has been tested against the Apache Directory Server)

```
DirContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext( env, null );

SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
searchControls.setSearchScope( SearchControls.OBJECT_SCOPE );
searchControls.setReturningAttributes( new String[]
    { "objectClasses" } );
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = ctx.search( "cn=schema", "(ObjectClass=*)", searchControls );

SearchResult result = results.next();
Attributes entry = result.getAttributes();

Attribute objectClasses = entry.get( "objectClasses" );
System.out.println( objectClasses );
```

Comment: You have to be careful when you hardcode cn=schema, this is implementation specific. Another minor point to note is the filter should be objectclass=subschema, but it does not matter.

Comment: nope, cn=schema is the LDAP V3 standard value specifying the schema location

Comment: What happens if cn=schema is returning 32 - No such object?

Answer (score 6):

```
DirContext schema=dcx.getSchema("");
NamingEnumeration bindings = schema.listBindings("ClassDefinition");
while (bindings.hasMore())
{
    Binding bd = (Binding)bindings.next();
    System.out.println(bd.getName() + ": " + bd.getObject());
}
```

You can use various other bindings like

- AttributeDefinition
- ClassDefinition
- SyntaxDefinition

Schema context may also provide bindings like

- MatchingRule
- ExtensionDefinition
- ControlDefinition
- SASLDefinition

Comment: The cast is not needed in Java 1.5 and above.

Comment: @RobinGreen , the binding is useless if he uses generics `NamingEnumeration<Binding>`, but it is useful in the example above.