# How to show all attributes definition present in LDAP schema using JNDI

Tags: ldap, jndi

I want to show all attributes definition present in LDAP schema to user.

```
DirContext schema = ctx.getSchema("");

Attributes answer = schema.getAttributes("AttributeDefinition/telephonenumber");
```

This code gives description about one attribute at a time and user also needs to know name of attribute. I want to show list of all attributes present in schema.

Can anyone please provide me sample code to show all attributes in LDAP directory using JNDI APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273022/how-to-show-all-objectclasses-description-of-ldap-directory-using-jndi) answer and use entry.get( "attributeTypes" ) to get all the attribute types

Comment: thank you.code worked fine. but just to mention schema location was cn=subschema for openldap and cn=schema for ibm-tds

Answer (score 0):

DirContext.getSchemaClassDefinition().